# SPFx SCSS - how do I reference third party classes along with my class to increase the specificity of my selector?

Tags: spfx-webparts, css

** For simplicity's sake I am not going to include all the Typescript stuff in my code examples here, so please just roll with it.

I'm using Semantic UI React as a UI component/styling framework for my SPFx webpart.

I have a button component that uses the Semantic UI Button component. Semantic UI adds its own classes `ui button` to its button component. I want to apply some extra styling to my button, so I added my own custom class.

`MyButton.module.scss`

```
.myButton {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

`MyButton.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import styles from './MyButton.module.scss';

export default class MyButton extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <Button className={styles.myButton} />
    );
  }
}
```

What ends up getting rendered in the HTML is

```
<button class="ui button myButton_123456"></button>
```

however, the extra styling I want added does not get applied because the Semantic UI CSS uses a selector of `.ui.button`, and while I can see the that the browser recognizes that my class/style is there, it only recognizes the style as applying to the selector `.myButton_123456`, so *the default Semantic CSS has greater specificity, and my style is ignored*.

Now if I were dealing with regular CSS, I know that I could define my custom style like this:

```
.ui.button.myButton {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

and my style would have more specificity and override the default Semantic styling.

However, if I put that in the SCSS module file, what I end up seeing is that those classes all get split up and are available as separate properties on the `style` object imported into my component.

If I just use my custom style alone, as I did originally, the HTML gets rendered the same, but in the browser CSS tools, I no longer see my class as a single class that's getting overridden by Semantics double class selector. It's just not there anymore.

And if I try something like

```
<Button className={`${styles.ui} ${styles.button} ${styles.myButton}`} />
```

then the HTML ends up like

```
<button class="ui button ui_123456 button_654321 myButton_987654"></button>
```

Now, in that case I win the specificity battle by having a triple-class selector, but it happens by inadvertently creating two new classes, which seems unnecessary.

So how can I structure things so that the browser ends up seeing

```
.ui.button.myButton_123456 {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

and correctly overrides the default Semantic styling by using Semantics own classes and one single new custom class?

---

Thanks to @theChrisKent for the answer, I've now learned a bit about `:global` and `:local` when using CSS modules.

Just wanted to add that the solution was not *exactly* as in the posted answer.  Trying to do

```
.myButton {
  :global {
    &.ui.button {
      margin-top: 1em;
    }
  }
}
```

gave me build errors saying "missing whitespace after :global", and looked like it was trying to construct the CSS like this:

```
.myButton :global.ui.button {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

The way I was able to get it to work was by constructing the SASS like this:

```
.myButton:global(.ui.button) {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

which comes across in the browser like

```
.myButton_123456.ui.button {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix your SCSS classes with known classes by using the :global selector. So you should be able to modify your SCSS like this:

```
.myButton {
  :global {
    &.ui.button {
      margin-top: 1em;
    }
  }
}
```

There's also the :local selector if you need to switch back while in the global scope.

Comment: `:global` worked, but not exactly the way you put as an example.  I've updated my question with the format of how it ended up working.